# Calculate directory size while recursing directory tree

Tags: java, file, recursion

This is my first post here so please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.
Also, this is a homework.

> A user selects a directory/folder and my program recursively shows all files and sub-directories under the selected directory. The program will also show the sizes of all the files and sub-directories.

I have done everything. The program works as expected. However, I used the FileUtils method from apache.commons.io to get size of a directory but apparently I'm not allowed to do that.

I can't use the apache.commons.io.

I can't use the Java nio package.

I can't create another method (separate method) that calculates directory size. This is what makes it hard.

I already have a recursion that is getting the names of all files and sub-directories. I'm thinking of adding something to that recursion algorithm that will give me the sum of all files under each directory but I just can't figure out how to do that.

Does anyone have ideas that can help?

```
private void recurseDirectory(File f) {

  if (f.isFile()) { 
      show f.getAbsPath() and f.length() on GUI }

  else if (f.isDirectory()) {
      show f.getAbsPath() and FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(f) on GUI }

      File[] files = f.listFiles();
      for (File file : files) { 
          recurseDirectory(file); }     
}
```

So instead of `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(f)`, in that part of the code I'd like to start adding sum of all files under that directory tree and then return that.

Comment: You could have `recurseDirectory` return an int that is the sum of all the file sizes in that directory. See: [File.length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length())

Comment: @JohnnyMopp File::length returns a long why cast it down to int?

Comment: @AlexC Ok. I didn't have the signature to `File.length()` memorized. You are correct.

Comment: The method needs to remain 'void'. I can't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating an inner Class inside a method of an outer class. And inside of this the inner class I created a method that calculates size of directory. I know this is not ideal, but this was a homework with tons of restrictions. Glad to get it working.

**OuterClass --> recursionMethod() --> InnerClass --> getDirSizeMethod()**

Class ListDirectory {

```
   private void recurseDirectory(File f) {

       class InnerClass {

           private long recurseFolder(File f) {
              long folderLength = 0;
              File[] files = f.listFiles();
              for (File file : files) {

                 if (file.isFile()) 
                     { folderLength += file.length(); }

                 else if (f.isDirectory()) 
                     { folderLength += recurseFolder(file); }   
              }
              return folderLength;
          }
      }

    if (f.isFile()) 
        { show f.getAbsolutePath() and f.length() on GUI }

    else if (f.isDirectory()) {

       InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
       long dirSize = inner.recurseFolder(f);

       show f.getAbsolutePath() and FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(f) on GUI }

       File[] files = f.listFiles();
       for (File file : files) 
         { recurseDirectory(file); }     
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do another method to calculate the size, which would also be recursive

```
private void recurseDirectory(File file) {
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + size(file));
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            recurseDirectory(f);
        }
    }
}

private long size(File file) {
    if(file.isFile()){
        return file.length();
    } else if(file.isDirectory()){
        long size = 0;
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            size += size(f);
        }
        return size;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew I could do that, but I'm not allowed to create a separate method. Ideally I'll do the directory size calculation in the recurseDirectory method, when file.isDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

```
private long recurseDirectory(File file) {
    if(file.isFile()){
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + file.length());
        return file.length();
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        long size = 0;
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            size += recurseDirectory(f);
        }
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + size);
        return size;

    }
    return 0;
}
```